# ETL Architecture for MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, database-design, architecture, etl

I'm working on a project that requires performing an ETL procedure from multiple MongoDB's into one. It is very crucial to record the update time of every field when performing the ETL (instead of one "updatedAt" field per document in the destination DB). What is the best practice for implementing this? Thanks!

(Open for suggestions to replace MongoDB as my database program.)